# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'WebServiceException' with message 'Invalid reference specified for parent_id'

Tags: php, vtiger

I have an issue using vtigercrm version 5.4.0. on Unix system.My issue is that I created a workflow for invoice with the task being generating an event in the calender.The condition is if any invoice entry is changed for a particular date event should be created in the calendar.

While clicking save on the invoice page the page gives an error :

`"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'WebServiceException' with message 'Invalid reference specified for parent_id' in /var/www/crmdemo/include/Webservices/Create.php:48 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/crmdemo/modules/com_vtiger_workflow/tasks/VTCreateEventTask.inc(97): vtws_create('Events', Array, Object(Users)) #1 /var/www/crmdemo/modules/com_vtiger_workflow/VTWorkflowManager.inc(275): VTCreateEventTask->doTask(Object(VTWorkflowEntity)) #2 /var/www/crmdemo/modules/com_vtiger_workflow/VTEventHandler.inc(98): Workflow->performTasks(Object(VTWorkflowEntity)) #3 /var/www/crmdemo/include/events/VTEventTrigger.inc(143): VTWorkflowEventHandler->handleEvent('vtiger.entity.a...', Object(VTEntityData)) #4 /var/www/crmdemo/include/events/VTEventsManager.inc(121): VTEventTrigger->trigger(Object(VTEntityData)) #5 /var/www/crmdemo/data/CRMEntity.php(816): VTEventsManager->triggerEvent('vtiger.entity.a...', Object(VTEntityData)) #6 /var/www/crmdemo/modules/Invoice/Save.php(47): CRMEntity->save('Invoice') #7 /var/www/crmdemo/index.php(749): includ in /var/www/crmdemo/include/Webservices/Create.php on line 48"`

But somehow the event is created in the calendar and other issue is while providing time for the event to be created the option button for "am/pm" I can choose pm but after saving it & loading the error page & visiting the same page it shows "am" even after choosing "pm"

I think it has something to do with php

m not able to paste all d file in here so heres the link

https://discussions.vtiger.com/index.php?p=/discussion/164995

Best Regards

Nevpro